# Why does joining meshes create new copies of a bunch of meshes?

Tags: mesh, particles

I have a bunch of tiny meshes on a plane that when I try to join them into one mesh, it creates multiple copies of every one of the tiny objects.

Here's before I join some of them:
[image]

And then here's after I join some of them:
[image]

The meshes were created from a particle system so maybe that has something to do with it, but other that I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You deleted the extra new line before the image listing. Hang on, I’ll fix it.